# Listview in navigation drawer not finding onItemClick event when used with another ListView

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I am building an application where I want to show a Navigation Drawer on a listview. Its Populating a drawer but when I click on the options on drawer, its not working, while the listview on activity working fine. sample code is as follows

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@color/border_list_view"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:background="@color/white" />
    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listMsg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@color/border_list_view"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How to implement this idea? If anyone can help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try use RecyclerView from android.support.v7.widget:
https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: Any other solution :(